# Variables dump to Javascript console

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there any equivalent of `var_export` or `var_dump` available in Drupal, that would output variables directly to the `console` object (FF, Chrome - `console.log()` or `console.info()`)?
I just don't feel like turning Devel & Themer stuff on and off every time I want to peek into variables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Drupal for Firebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) module (which can be used with Chrome or Firefox) has a `firep()` function built in which will log a `print_r` of any variable passed to it into the Drupal for Firebug widget. That might be an option.

If you really want a console log, though, I think you'd have to write the functionality yourself. It isn't too hard though, here's a quick module I knocked up that works well for me:

File: js_debug.info

```
name = JS Debug
core = 7.x
```

File: js_debug.module

```
function js_debug_log($var = NULL) {
  $log = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  if ($var) {
    $log[] = $var;
  }

  return $log;
}

function js_debug_page_alter(&$page) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'js_debug') . '/js_debug.js', 'file');
  drupal_add_js(array('js_debug' => array('messages' => js_debug_log())), 'setting');
}
```

File: js_debug.js

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    if (Drupal.settings.js_debug.messages) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Drupal.settings.js_debug.messages.length; i++) {
        console.log(Drupal.settings.js_debug.messages[i]);
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The above code is obviously very bare, and doesn't check to make sure `console.log()` is available, etc. But it will work fine in Chrome/Firefox for any var (including arrays and objects).

To use, simply call `js_debug_log($var);` from code; the variable you pass will be logged in the console as you'd expect.

Comment: I edited the js_debug_page_alter function to add the js file :) Now works like a charm! Thanks a bunch Clive!

Comment: @Artur Sorry about that, I had that bit in a `hook_init()` function which I somehow managed to miss when I copied and pasted!

Comment: No problem whatsoever, it's always kind of a useful lesson!

Comment: @Clive, is there any particular reason you are using hook_pager_alter here instead of something else?  It is because it is a "late" hook in the page generation process?

Comment: @MPD That was my thinking yes. I couldn't think of another hook that would get called later, but still in time to actually be included in the current page request